# Delete item from list not rendering react js

Tags: reactjs

I am displaying table from API, so when I click to delete it should delete

Now it's deleting actually. but the problem is it's not rendering the output

Here is my code for that function

```
  const delpersonHandler = index => {
    const apiDel = api;
    console.log(index);
    api.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(api);
    setApi({ ...api, apiDel });
  };
```

here is where i call that

```
 <TableCell align="Justify">
   <Button variant="outlined">Edit</Button>
   <Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => delpersonHandler(id)}>
      Delete
   </Button>
 </TableCell>
```

full code is available here

https://pastebin.com/u7fAefBH

Comment: that api is the state... ( useState )

Comment: I Found this as answer, any other good method ?  const temp = [...api];
    temp.splice(id, 1);
    setApi(temp);
    console.log("state updated", api);

Comment: The above will work well.

Answer (score 3):

React states are immutable hence doing `api.splice(index, 1);` does not work because you're directly affecting the React state.

`api` is an array but you're setting an object in the `setApi` setter function

the simplest way to do this is

```
    const delpersonHandler = index => {
        let oldApi = [...api] // new array containing api's elements
        oldApi.splice(index,1); 
        setApi(oldApi);
      };
```

Comment: Yep.. Refer my answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working with functional components, the `useState` hook delivers two values, specifically the getter and setter of your state, invoking the last one with some parameter will set a new value and invoke a render call.

In the example, `setApi` is this setter method, but you are calling it with an object as parameter instead an array. And by using the `splice` method with the `api` value is possible to inferer that it must be an array. So you need to call the setter with the same variable type:

```
const delpersonHandler = index => {
  // Don't apply changes directly, instead clone it and modify it.
  const newApi = api.slice();
  newApi.splice(index, 1);

  // Pass an array instead an object
  setApi(newApi); 
};
```

Comment: "the useState hook delivers two values, specifically the getter and setter of your prop" - `useState`, as implied by the name, is used for **state**, **not props**.

Comment: i followed your code.. its deleting, but its not rendering.. https://imgur.com/a/bfDTxgJ

Comment: @LogeshP Did you receive some warning in the console?

Comment: pls see the image.. i attached here on previous comment

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix by using the below code

```
const delpersonHandler = index => {
const apiDel= [...api]; //getting the current state of array using spread operator
apiDel.splice(index, 1);  //deleting based on index
setApi(apiDel);
console.log("state updated", api);
}
```

[...api] without this line this wasn't working